# Firebase: How to allow user to disable push notifications in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have added push notifications for my app in Flutter which are working fine but I also have a functionality where the user can disable the notifications.

How do I allow user to disable firebase push notifications?

**Edit**

I decided to use One Signal using the below steps

https://onesignal.com/blog/how-to-add-push-notifications-in-flutter-with-onesignal/

Comment: send the user to the phone settings to turn off the notification

Answer (score 0):

I'm supposing you're subscribing your user to a certain topic. With this in mind, you could use the [`unsubscribeFromTopic()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging#unsubscribeFromTopic(java.lang.String)) method.

Also, you can read more about the [firebase_messaging](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging) API and documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessaging).

Comment: I am not subscribing the user to any topic.Its just some general notifications I was sending.

Comment: Then you can use the `deleteToken()` method when disabling, and the `getToken()` method when enabling the notifications back.